# Efficiently calculate \$-x-y\$ using a single adder

Tags: vhdl, math, adder

I would like to know if there is an efficient way of implementing the operation \$-x-y\$ on an FPGA using only a single chain of adders or subtractors, roughly equal in length to the maximum number of bits in \$x\$ and \$y\$.

The bit twiddling trick of replacing \$-x\$ by \$\overline x + 1\$ (\$\overline x\$ meaning bitwise negation) results in the expressions \$\overline x - y + 1\$ or \$\overline x + \overline y + 2\$. Both expressions I don't know how to calculate. How do you perform a subtraction with a positive carry or an addition with a carry of 2?

Comment: Why don't you just realize that \$-x-y=-\left(x+y\right)\$ and simply perform a normal sum (a well-worn path) and then negate the result (easy?)

Comment: Negating is not easy, it requires inverting every bit and adding 1, which is another full adder. It would be nice if this addition of 1 could be somehow included in the first addition as a carry or similar.

Comment: Isn't this just \$\overline{x}+\overline{y}+2\$? Why is that hard?

Comment: Because I can't add 2 with a single carry and if I don't use a carry it's another full addition.

Comment: Why not add 2 into the 2nd stage? Just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 2nd stage? Do you mean the 2nd LSB? Adding the 2 there is only possible when there is no carry from the first bit. Otherwise it would again generate a carry of 2 which I don't know how to propagate.

Comment: You only need a half adder for bit 0 and always adding 1, plus carry in from bit 0, isn't complex for bit 1. The rest is standard fare. I was merely inquiring, since I don't know anything about your function blocks or level of coding. Just a question to you, is all.

Comment: How do you handle the case when \$\overline x\$ and \$\overline y\$ are all '1' bits (all bits set). Then you get a carry from bit 0 and for bit 1 you have to add four '1' bits which results in a carry larger than 1.

Answer (score 6):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

--Donald Knuth

If you want to do it **efficiently**, let the synthesis tools choose the best implementation. Just use an HDL to describe the behavior you want. Most FPGAs include some kind of optimized structures for addition, and if you try to force the synthesizer to use some bizarre method that looks good on paper you may get very poor results.

Comment: The synthesis tool just creates two sequential additions. So for 32bit inputs I end up with 64 logic elements. I'm just wondering if it can be done in arround 32 LE.

Comment: You could try adjusting the optimization constraints to see if the compiler will choose a **smaller** but **slower** implementation. The tools don't know what you mean by "efficient" unless you tell them.

Comment: I can conceive of tricks to add the 2 LSBs of xbar, ybar and 2 separately, generating a carry to feed into an auto-generated adder with carry input for the rest of xbar and ybar, but it would be slow. The speed/area tradeoff is something you have to do routinely in FPGAs. If you have speed to spare, consider using a serial implementation, much more area efficient. If you need more speed than a pure 1 bit serial architecture, then use serial pairs, nybbles, bytes, or 16 bit words, or even non-powers-of-2 for that matter.

Comment: I don't think this will even work. Adding the 2 LSBs of xbar, ybar and 2 may result in a carry of 2 which a normal adder can not handle.